# RadioButton: setting focus from view code not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, radio-button, focus

If a user is logged in or already entered his personal data in checkout process, the radio button gets class `focus` and `active` from the view code (salutation = true means user is a *mister userxy*):

```
<label class="btn btn-secondary btn-salutation @(salutation && (loggedIn || WebShopSession.Instance().WebShopCheckout.IsSalutationSet) ? "focus active" : "")">
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Salutation, true, new { @class = "visibleradio" }) Herr
</label>
```

[image]

Visually, this works well (and classes are set, as you can see above):

[image]

But when I click on the button to continue to next step, I get a validation error saying that the radio button is not set.

Strange thing is, the same method works fine at another place in checkout, when setting delivery and payment from view code

```
<label for="@("shippingoption" + currentShipping)" class="btn btn-secondary btn-salutation @(shippingMethod.Id == WebShopSession.Instance().WebShopCheckout.ShippingID ? "active focus" : "")" onclick="setShippingData('@(shippingMethod.Name)', '@(shippingMethod.Price)')">
```

As you may notice, in the first lines of code the class order is *focus active* and in the second example it is *active focus*, but I also tried to change this and it had no effect ;)

**EDIT**:
I also tried to give the radio buttons ids and added `for="radiouniqueid"` to label, but that didn´t make a change.

**EDIT**:
I also tried this:

```
<label class="btn btn-secondary btn-salutation focus active">
```

which works on other radio buttons but not here.

The whole group looks like this:

```
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-secondary btn-salutation @(salutation && (loggedIn || WebShopSession.Instance().WebShopCheckout.IsSalutationSet) ? "focus active" : "")">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Salutation, true, new { @class = "visibleradio" }) Herr
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-secondary btn-salutation @(!salutation && (loggedIn || WebShopSession.Instance().WebShopCheckout.IsSalutationSet) ? "focus active" : "")">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Salutation, false, new { @class = "visibleradio" }) Frau
        </label>
    </div>
```

So, what is it I am not seeing here?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes you are blind while coding ...

I needed to set the attribute `Checked` like this:

```
<label class="btn btn-secondary btn-salutation @(salutation && (loggedIn || WebShopSession.Instance().WebShopCheckout.IsSalutationSet) ? "focus active" : "")">
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Salutation, true, new { @class = "visibleradio", @Checked = salutation && (loggedIn || WebShopSession.Instance().WebShopCheckout.IsSalutationSet) ? "checked" : "" }) Herr
</label>
```